# Passing JSON as a parameter swift

Tags: swift, rx-swift, swifty-json, moya

I am making an api call which requires me to pass JSON as paramter. when I do that, it crashes the application. I am using Moya for my networking so I decided to use SwiftyJSON to get JSON directly to the body but the app crashes saying `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (__SwiftValue)`

```
public var task: Task {
        switch self {
        case .postCheckout(let cart): return .requestParameters(parameters: ["cart": cart], encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
        }
    }
```

my moya

```
func postCheckout(cart: JSON) -> Observable<BaseResponseModel> {

        return provider.rx.request(.postCheckout(cart: cart))
            .mapObject(BaseResponseModel.self)
            .asObservable()
    }
```

when I printed the JSON this is what gets printed

```
{
  "total" : 6000,
  "subscription" : {
    "id" : 4,
    "quantity" : 3
  },
  "vas" : [
    4,
    6,
    2
  ]
}
```

Comment: Send json string instead of json object. Make json data and convert it into string object using `utf-8` encoding.

Comment: I did that but the it requires a JSON

Comment: I'm not familiar with Moya but in general we send json string. Because raw request doesn't understand the local language object.

Comment: `["cart": cart]` if you pass `cart` as dictionary param then it should work. Example: `.requestParameters(parameters: ["cart": ["total": 6000, "user": "me"]], encoding: JSONEncoding.default)`

Comment: that worked add it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general we send `JSON string` not `JSON object`. Make `JSON` data and convert it into string object using `utf-8` encoding.

But `Moya` do this conversion itself so in `["cart": cart]` if you pass cart as dictionary param then it should work.

**Example:**

```
 .requestParameters(parameters: ["cart": ["total": 6000, "user": "me"]], encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
```